# Stop button in eclipse, stops TestNG test process without going through Teardown method

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

I use stop button to kill the TestNG process in eclipse (shown in the attachment), the test suite gets killed immediately without calling Teardown method(the selenium browser which I opened for this test suite in Setup method is still open.).

I tried using the TestNG annotations like @AfterMethod, @AfterTest, @AfterSuite for the Teardown method. None of these annotations help to reach the Teardown code.

I read in TestNG website that if I use listeners, then I can make testNG process to hit the Teardown method when OnTestSuccess, OnTestFailure, OnTestSkipped...

But I don't think the listeners will help, as the testNG results shows all the test cases that are run so far as passed and NO test is shown as skipped.

I don't think try and catch will help as no exceptions are thrown when I hit the eclipse STOP button.
[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The stop button is killing the testng process. That's why after methods are not called.

I think nothing exists to stop the test  execution and to call after methods or listeners after. 
You can ask for the feature on https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues or https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must have a cleanup invoked when the JVM exits (gracefully or forcibly), you can try adding that cleanup as a [ShutdownHook](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_addshutdownhook.htm).

Read more about Shutdown hooks [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html).